# How do I configure a pin to be a bidirectional and open collector?

Tags: pins, port-mapping

I want to communicate with a keyboard asynchronously through a single open collector, bidirectional data pin. As part of the protocol, the data pin is active low and is pulled low by either the host or connected device.

Some code examples configure the pin direction to switch input to output depending on wether the host want to input or output a signal. Constantly switching the pin directions seems a bit naive.

Are there better methods?

Comment: Depends on the MCU in use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the other end of the link has the same signal voltage as your
Arduino, you can simulate an open collector with a single pin:

- `digitalWrite(pin, LOW); pinMode(pin, OUTPUT);` sets the pin to output
  an active low signal.
- `pinMode(pin, INPUT_PULLUP)` sets the pin to input mode, or output
  passive high which, in open-collector mode, is the same thing.

Note that in the first case the order of the commands is important: on
AVR microcontrollers, if you set the mode to `OUTPUT` before writing
`LOW`, the pin will for a short time output an active high, which is
forbidden in open-collector mode. I don't know how other MCUs would
behave in the same situation though.

**Edit** to address Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams’ comment: An open-collector
bus needs a pullup resistor on each data line to function properly. If
that pullup is already provided by your keyboard, or your cable, then
you should use `pinMode(pin, INPUT)` to accurately emulate an
open-collector output on the Arduino side. Otherwise you have to provide
that pullup, either as an external component or by using the internal
pullup of the MCU. Beware that the latter may be a little bit weak,
depending on your data rate.

Comment: You do not want the pullup enabled if you are trying to accurately emulate an OC output.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Right. I edited my answer to address this very valid point.

Comment: Depending on the data rate it also may be good to write the pins PORT and DDR registers directly, which works way faster than usage of `digitalWrite()`. Though for slow communication it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Just to clarify, issuing those two commands will enable the pin to input and output a signal?  Correct?  Also, just for out of curiosity, could splitting the data pin between an input and output pin work as well?  Thanks.

Comment: @ATL_DEV: Yes, that's it. Splitting the data pin can work, but it will not make matters simpler, and it is essentially pointless.